# How do I send data from activity A to activity B without using firebase?

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on an "Order food from home" restaurant app.
What I am trying to do is to send the quantity of a product (a bottle of CocaCola for example) from the activity that includes only the juice to the "Shopping Cart" activity where I will calculate the price and then show both the quantity and the total price of the product.

My problem is that I can't really figure out how to send information from activity A to activity B.

If possible, I would like doing that without using a database. (Through intents for example)
This code shows on the activity with the juice the quantity of CocaCola's the customer wishes to buy. I want to send this quantity in the shoppingCart activity.

Code:

```
public void displayCantitateCocaCola(int number){
    TextView quantityText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cantitateCola);
    quantityText.setText("" + number);
}
```

So, if the above method's display is 3, I want to get that value in the shopping cart activity.

Comment: The standard way to go is to store the quantity in memory within a java object , for example "order". Use Parceler to make it Parcelable and send it as intent data. Or just send the quantity value as an int extra.  see https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Building

Answer (score 0):

did you try to send your data inside intent? 
when you are moving from activity a to b use this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2091482/6565331
   Fast answer:
Activity A:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(A.this,B.class)
i.putExtra("key", YOUR VALUE);
Startactivity(i)
```

Activity B on create:

```
Int value=0; 
 Intent intent= getIntent();
 Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
 if(b!=null) { 
Int value =(Int) b.get("key");
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand that example... Can you please explain it to me?
Like give an example where you name everything so I can understand it all. I am a beginner so that would be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: How do you move from activity A to activity B?

Comment: That's what I am trying to find out.....

Comment: I edited my answer check those codes please